# How do you make dynamically loaded form automatically setup with jqBootstrapvalidation

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have several forms on my website that are loaded dynamically and I don't want to have to call the following JavaScript in every ajax return that has a form:

```js
$("input,select,textarea").not("[type=submit]").jqBootstrapValidation();
```

Is there some way to use delegation to get this to work? I saw one older example that had:

```js
$("input,select,textarea").not("[type=submit]").live().jqBootstrapValidation();
```

But of course `live()` is deprecated. Is there some way to use `on()` instead?